# "time" evolving metric tensor and Riemann curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

I have an $n-$dimensional manifold. On the manifold, I have a set of 1-forms L which depend parametrically on a "time" variable. In other words, in a coordinate patch $L(t)=u_i(t,x^1,\ldots,x^n)dx^i$ with $t>=0$. Starting from a given metric tensor at $t=0$, I evolve it in time according to
$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}=\widetilde{\nabla_t L(t)}
$$
where the tilde represents the symmetric part of its argument, and $\nabla_t$ is the covariant derivative with the Levi-Civita connection of the metric $g(t)$.
In a coordinate patch
$$
\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial t}=\left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x^j}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x^i}-2u_p\Gamma^p_{ij}(t)\right)
$$

I want the Riemann curvature tensor to remain constant in time, set by the curvature of the initial metric $g(0)$. Do I need to impose additional conditions on $L(t)$?

Comment: I do not think your evolution equation is well-defined (unless $M$ is parallelizable).

Comment: Have you tried to do the calculation?

Comment: @Deane, I was hoping in some general results, but I may have to bite the bullet.

Comment: Why wouldn't the equation be valid for a manifold which is not parallelizzabile? The r.h.s. should be well defined for any $M$, or am I missing something?

Comment: @user3646557, you might also want to compute $$\partial_t(F_t^*g)$$ where $F_t$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: I found these variation formulas that apply to my case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Variation_formulas.